# Call to a member function find() on a non-object simple html dom in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, simple-html-dom

I am working on HTML DOM in laravel 5.2.

$html = new Htmldom($home_url);

When i print $html object it display crawl results but when i use $html->find('div') then it gives an error "Call to a member function find() on a non-object"

Comment: Is `$home_url` set correctly? Does that HTML have a DTD, `<!DOCTYPE html>`..?

Comment: Issue is resolved.
Thanks